# What is the difference in usage between 港 and 港湾?

Tags: words, word-usage, wago-and-kango

According to my dictionary, 港湾{こうわん} and 港{みなと} both means *harbour*. What is the difference between the usage of these two words ?

Answer (score 1):

港湾 is a kango (Sino-Japanese word) and 港 is a wago (native Japanese word). Thus the former is used in formal documents and such, whereas 港 is preferred in casual conversations and lyrics. See similar questions tagged with [wago-and-kango](/questions/tagged/wago-and-kango).